# Problem with starting SPDesigner workflow programmatically

Tags: designer-workflow, web-part-page

When we start SharePoint Designer workflow, which updates an item in the list, from code on custom web part page (with custom webpart added on it), we got following error:

```
System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceException: Updates are not currently allowed for GET requests...
```

We use `SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates=true;` so this is not a problem. When we start this workflow manually, or from event receiver for example, everything works fine. Error occurs only when we start it from custom web part page. When we start a workflow which doesn't update an item everything works, too. Also, if we use Pause For Duration (5 minutes) action in workflow before update, it works! Do you have any idea?